# Concat columns from query result in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that has a column with labels in a single cell. A cell can contain 1 or more labels, each separated by a comma.

```
+-----------+
| Labels    |
+-----------+
| Foo,Bar   |
| Bar,Baz   |
| Quux,Quuz |
```

I want to create a formula that generates a a column with all the unique labels separately in a row. For the example above this would be the following.

```
+-----------+
| Labels    |
+-----------+
| Foo       |
| Bar       | 
| Baz       |
| Quux      |
| Quuz      |
```

I have figured out that I can use the `SPLIT` function to obtain the labels separately. If I add to that the use of `ARRAYFORMULA` I can get a matrix of the values. But then I'm stuck with that matrix, and how to turn all the columns into a single column. To solve that I know you can use the `{RANGE, RANGE}` syntax. To apply the `{}` to the result of an `ARRAYFORMULA` I use a `QUERY` to pick out all the columns.

This gives me the following:

```
=UNIQUE(
  {
    QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:A4, ","))), "Select Col1");
    QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:A4, ","))), "Select Col2");
    QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1:A4, ","))), "Select Col3")
  }
)
```

The problem with this approach is that it works for Labels that contain up to three comma-separated values, and there has to be at least one cell with three comma-separated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do just what you need.
Give it a try

```
=QUERY(INDEX(IFERROR(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A2:A9,",")))),"WHERE Col1<>'' ",0)
```

Comment: Have you tried the given answer? If it works for you it would be nice to accept. If not let me know so I can fix it.